# Passing a JSON string with a the hash character # to a Xamarin form and truncates data

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a pretty standard Xamarin form that uses template pages for some overview data. When the user taps an entry I take them to a details page. The data comes from a server via an API. The details is held in a class behind the overview form/template. When the user taps the form I Jsonconvert.SerializeOvbject and pass it to the details page for processing. This process works fine under normal conditions. However when the data has a hash tag # (aka pound, aka sharp) in the data the the json is truncated at the point where it appeared in the string.
The meat of the tapped event in the template:

```
                    var forminfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ea.Parameter);
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TrackWarrantPageX), typeof(TrackWarrantPageX));
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TrackWarrantPageX)}?{nameof(TrackWarrantPageX.Contentx)}={forminfo}");
```

However in the details page the string that is received is truncated at the # sign.
Here is how the string arrives at the details page (only relevant code is shown).

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[QueryProperty(nameof(Contentx), nameof(Contentx))]
public partial class TrackWarrantPageX : ContentPage
{
    string contentx = "";
    public string Contentx
    {
        get => contentx;
        set
        {
            contentx = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value ?? string.Empty);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            PopulateForm(contentx); *<<<===== this is the first place I can inspect the contents and it is truncated*
        }
    }
```

I played around with this line

> contentx = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value ?? string.Empty);

and did some research but came up short. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume the problem occurs when you pass the serialized string via `GoToAsync`.  Have you tried URLencoding it at that point, and decoding it when received?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jason suggestion I researched `URLencoding` and stumbled upon `Uri.EscapDataString (encode)`. Since the page performed a `Uri.UnescapeDataString (decode)` it would best to encode it first. So I added one line of code on the tap event of the template and it looks like this:

```
var forminfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ea.Parameter);
string _forminfo = Uri.EscapeDataString(forminfo); <<<===NEW LINE OF CODE
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TrackWarrantPageX)}?{nameof(TrackWarrantPageX.Contentx)}={_forminfo }");
```

So now the string is preserved on the page side. Thanks Jason.